# Accidentally deleted xcode project scheme

Tags: ios

I was in the xcode section where we can change project target(one with blueprint icon in project navigator) and I think I accidentally pressed 'del' and then maybe 'enter'

I can still access the files from finder and inside the editor. And also the place on top where we select simulator device tells me to add scheme.

EDIT: [SOLVED] thanks everyone for replies and help i just ran 'install pod' command again and it came back.

Comment: You also seem to have a keyboard issue ;-) You don't have a Git repository?

Comment: You can simply create new scheme. Another option create new project and drag and drop everything and add required framework and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED IT MYSELF:
Just closed the project and ran the "pod install" command again and everything cane back to normal.